# Rails error 'First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I've tried all different Stack posts on how to get rid of the error '
First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty' and none of their solutions are working for me.

My app involves making posts, where users can upload images. Rather than taking image url's, I want them to be able to upload straight from their file system.

Here's my controller:

```
  class PostsController < ApplicationController
      before_action :all_posts, only: [:feed, :create]
      respond_to :html, :js

    def show
      @post = Post.find_by_id(params['id'])
    end


    def create
      @post = Post.create(post_params)
    end

    def new
      @post = Post.new
    end

    private

    def all_posts
      @posts = Post.all
    end

    def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(:caption, :content, :image)
    end

  end
```

And new.html.erb:

```
<footer>
  <%= form_for @post, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :caption %>
    <%= f.text_field :content %>
    <%= f.file_field :image %>
    <%= f.submit %>
  <% end %>
</footer>
```

People keep suggesting adding @post = Post.new to the form and the action, yet none have been working for me.

Also, I've already checked my database, and I have 7 posts currently in there.

Thanks so much for the help.

Comment: which is your corresponding controller action? Your view is: `feed.html.erb`
You should have a `feed` action in your `posts_controller`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting this error because your `@post` in `nil` when you call the `form_for(@post,....`

You have to instantiate the `@post` instance variable in your controller's corresponding action. As you don't have it right now, hence you are getting this error.

By looking at your rest of the code, I think you want to upload the post in your `new.html.erb` file NOT `feed.html.erb` as you mentioned in the question.

Comment: Okay, thanks. Now I'm getting the error: "undefined method `posts_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fcd2bec39c0>:0x007fcd2bec23e0>". Do you know why this could be happening?

Comment: Where are you getting this error? could you please share the full error stacktrace?

Comment: I changed the action to feed, and now:     NoMethodError in Posts#feed  undefined method `posts_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fcd2bec39c0>:0x007fcd2bec23e0>  And it highlights: <%= form_for @post, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f| %>
        <%= f.text_field :caption %>
        <%= f.text_field :content %>
        <%= f.file_field :image %>

Comment: can you try change the view to `new.html.erb` and keep the action as `new`?

Comment: I changed the view to new.html.erb, and adjusted everything with it, yet I'm still getting the same error

Comment: oh ok, you need to change your route. Please post the content of your `routes.rb`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87721/discussion-between-k-m-rakibul-islam-and-jake-r).